# Connection failed to MSSQL in php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have this code to connect to my sql server :

```
<?php 

$serverName = "DESKTOP-P87SVPI\MSSQLSERVER";

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"map2");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

if ($conn){
echo "finally";
}
else {
print_r( sqlsrv_errors());

}
?>
```

I got this error  :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbrDF.png) => 87
>   [code] => 87 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1KwG.png) => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL
>   Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server
>   Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbrDF.png) =>
>   Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbrDF.png) => 0 [code] => 0 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1KwG.png) =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout
>   expired ) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1KwG.png) => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbrDF.png) => 87
>   [code] => 87 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1KwG.png) => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. ) )

I checked this in MSSQL:

```
select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename
```

And it's the same :

```
DESKTOP-P87SVPI\MSSQLSERVER
```

And These are the drivers I have in phpInfo():
[image]

Also I checked the remote connection in MSSQL and it's allowed.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to connect but also having problem so I added `ConnectionPooling=0` in the connection then it worked !

```
 try {


$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=serverName\serverInstance,1433;Database=db;ConnectionPooling=0", "user", "pass");

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aer u sure that your server is not using password?

Try to hook up the conenction with PDO:

```
    <?php
  try {
    $hostname = "localhost/MSSQLSERVER";
    $port = 10060;
    $dbname = "dbname";
    $username = "dbuser";
    $pw = "password";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select name from master..sysdatabases where name = db_name()");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
  unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

That should do the Job, if not it has something to do with the setup from your SQL-Server!

Comment: I'm using windows authentication it doesn't matter there is a pass or not

Comment: mysql:host ? I'm using MSSQL

Comment: I'm getting an exception from your solution : couldn't find driver , but thanks